# PHPExcel copy data into new document

Tags: php, phpexcel, setvalue, getvalue

is it possible with PHPExcel to import data from a .xlsx with for example "getValue()" and write it in a new excel document?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Why don't you try doing it and see for yourself

Comment: I'm searching for myself since 3 days and didnt found it...

Comment: Load the file you want to copy from.... create a new PHPExcel instance.... get the value from the first file's worksheet/cell.... set that cell value in the new PHPExcel object's worksheet..... there are plenty of [examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Examples) with PHPExcel showing how to read files, get data from worksheets, store data in worksheets, create new files, etc